# How to provide $apollo for Nuxt 2 Bridge composition API?

Tags: nuxt.js, apollo, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3, nuxt-bridge

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/nuxt-modules/apollo/issues/288) with some examples of using `@vue/apollo-composable` but they don't work with Nuxt 2 Bridge.

Answer (score 0):

`plugins/provide-apollo-client.ts`

```js
import { provideApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  provideApolloClient(nuxtApp.apolloProvider?.defaultClient)
})
```

`Component.vue`

```html
<script setup lang="ts">

const { $apollo } = useNuxtApp()

</script>
```